# How to delete vertical line from string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For some reason I can't delete the vertical bar from a string. This string was extracted from an html tag (BeautifulSoup 4).

The string comes from the title meta tag of a site.

Example input: 'How to run very fast | running.com'
By the if statement, the string still contains the |, but it is not detected in name and never enters the if statement...

```
name = title.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()

#remove everything after | because often it is SEO stuff
name = re.sub('\|', '',  name)  #fails
if "|" in name:
    lineIndex = name.index('|')
    name = name[:lineIndex]
```

Comment: use `r` as `r'\|'` (I think if I am not wrong)

Comment: Just tried, failed...

Comment: I tried, it worked for me.

Comment: If `r'\|'` doesn't work, then it's likely a different character.

Comment: What do you get with `name.split('|')[0]`? If you still get the same string back, then its another character not `|`.

Comment: Just figured it out... the lowercase l and the vertical bar look exactly alike in the debugger...

Comment: I think this should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to treat the regex as a raw string:

```
s = 'How to run very fast | running.com'
s = re.sub(r'\|', '',  s)

>>> print s
How to run very fast  running.com
```

Demo: http://repl.it/R8m

Comment: @WilliamFalcon, Try the demo I have posted. It does work

Comment: Your demo works... I just figured it out. It was a lowercase l, that looked exactly like the vertical bar in my debugger... i used r('\sl\s', '', s), to replace it

Comment: @WilliamFalcon, Glad I could (sorta) be of help. :P

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to remove everything after '|', then you should change your regex.

```
x = 'Blah | blah'
x = re.sub('\|.*', '', x)

>>> print x
'Blah '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) for this.

> Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and
>   then translate the characters using table, which must be a
>   256-character string giving the translation for each character value,
>   indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character
>   deletion step is performed.

Example:

```
s = 'How to run very fast | running.com'

print s

s = s.translate(None, '|')

print s
```

Output:

```
How to run very fast | running.com
How to run very fast  running.com
```

Or using the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method:

```
foo = 'How to run very fast | running.com'

bar = foo.replace("|", "")

print foo
print bar
```

Output:

```
How to run very fast | running.com
How to run very fast  running.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting everything before the first | occurrence should work:

```
name = name.split('|')[0]
```

if also want to discard trailing and leading white spaces:

```
name = name.strip()
```

(note that will also work even if | is not in name)

Comment: You may want to check for the existence of a | in the string first, to avoid any errors.

Comment: Just because is the leading part what is needed it will work even if theres is no | in the string.

Comment: If you split a string on `|` and there is not one in the string, then the result will be an empty array, in which case `array[0]` will throw an error.